# Understanding pandas.Series.str.replace behavior when I try to pass pat as a list?

Tags: python, pandas

The signature of the subject method is [`Series.str.replace(self, pat, repl, n=-1, case=None, flags=0, regex=True)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) where:

> pat:str or compiled regex
>
> String can be a character sequence or regular expression.
>
> repl : str or callable
>
> Replacement string or a callable. The callable is passed the regex match object and must return a replacement string to be used. See re.sub()

Example: `pd.Series(['a','b',5,np.nan]).str.replace(['a'],'999')` results in a series with all NaNs

Why does this convert my entire column to NaNs if I pass `pat` as a list. It should throw an error if it does not see a list as a regex compiled pattern or a string. what is causing this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't state the version, but I confirm in pandas 1.3 it throws an error if you try to pass `pat` as a list:

```
pd.Series(['a','b',5,np.nan]).str.replace(['a'],'999')

TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Beyond that, the place to file a bug/enhance request on pandas is https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues. (They are responsive to enhance requests, see this one they implemented: [Should str.replace accept a compiled expression? #15446](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/15446) back in 0.20)